# ROS Groovy Gazebo version

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I want to migrate from ROS Fuerte to ROS Groovy. I'm afraid about the version of Gazebo that is in ROS Groovy since I had a similar problem in the migration from ROS Electric to ROS Fuerte some months ago. I succeed in transforming the old model (.xacro) in the new format (.sdf) but they are compatible only for Gazebo version 1.0. Then, if ROS Groovy includes the new version of Gazebo (1.2) I might have some troubles.
If ROS Groovy include Gazebo version 1.2, is there someone with the same problem (i.e. transforming .xacro or earlier .sdf into new .sdf files)?
Is there any guide how to migrate from ROS Fuerte to ROS Groovy?

Thanks in advance,

Neostek

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51170/ros-groovy-gazebo-version/) by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2012-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [release documentation](http://ros.org/wiki/groovy#Gazebo), Groovy *will* include gazebo 1.2.

Note that Groovy is still in Beta status, not officially released yet.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-02**:
Groovy just officially released today.